# OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS - how to prevent Delta E class from query

Tags: sabre

Delta has introduced new economy fares that are in E class.  United has something similar.  When we price in Sabre Red, we now have to add #MPC-ANY to our pricing commands (For bulk fares: WPPJCB‡NCB‡MPC-ANY‡RQ, and For published fares: WPNCB‡MPC-ANY‡RQ).

How can I prevent these from showing up in the SOAP OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS request?  I've not been successful in finding what to put in my OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS request.  I don't see this MPC-ANY command in the documentation (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max/resources).

I guess these fares are called "Basic Economy Fares". One of the pricing SOAP requests had /Price?requestInformation/OptionalQualifiers/PricingQualifiers/BasicEconomyExclude. However, I've not found something similar for the OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.

I found this, but there is no way to exclude Basic Economy out of Economy.
http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/shopping/BargainFinderMaxRQ_v3-1-0_Design.xml
CabinPref PreferLevel="Preferred" Cabin="Y"

Answer (score 1):

If you're an existing customer, a request can be filed from eservices, to request classes of service from being filtered out:

American Form = https://agencyeservices.sabre.com/Manager/Ordering/Basic-Economy-Inhibit-Request-for-American.aspx

Delta Form = https://agencyeservices.sabre.com/Manager/Ordering/Basic-Economy-Inhibit-Request-for-Delta.aspx

United Form = https://agencyeservices.sabre.com/Manager/Ordering/Basic-Economy-Inhibit-Request-for-United.aspx

Comment: I want to be able to turn it on/off via the request.  I don't want to permanently remove them.